# Install windows in a partition without OS, without formatting it

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, installation

I have an HDD with two partitions, one with Win 7, and one with data.

On the partition with Win 7, I want to format and install Linux, no problems there. But in the other, I want to install a fresh Win 7, without removing the data on that partition.

Will Win 7 installer let me install (fresh, not repair) without formatting the partition and keeping all the existing data?

Comment: @Karan - Yep, I was.  You can update your answer in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ***definitely*** possible to [install Windows without formatting](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/installing-reinstalling-windows#1TC=windows-7) an existing NTFS partition with data.

1. Just ensure you select **Custom** installation when asked:

   [image: 1]
2. Choose the appropriate partition:

   [image: 2]

   Here if you don't click on **Drive options (advanced)** and choose to format the partition, its existing contents (except for any Windows-related files and folders from a previous installation) will remain *untouched*.
3. If Setup detects a previous Windows installation on the same partition it will show you the following prompt:

   [image: 3]
4. The end result will be that you'll have Windows installed afresh on the partition (with or without a **Windows.old** folder as the case may be) along with any existing data the partition already contained.
5. Finally you should install Linux so that Grub will enable you to boot into both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I ended up backing up the data and formatting the entire disk, but it's good to know this anyway.

Comment: Yep, I've installed versions from Win95 onwards with existing data in the same partition and had no issues.

Comment: Awesome . You saved me a lot of work of backing up . Thank you for explaining this so well

Answer (score -2):

No. Your best bet is to use minitool partition manager free version. Move/resize your data hdds partition all the way to the end of the drive and then create a 400 mb system reserved partition and set it as active and then make another partition in the centre of the drive. This will be your os drive.

Now click on the apply button

If there is a bsod, don't panic everything is fine unless you converted MBR to gpt

Now install windows 7

You can then shrink and extend your data partition using partition manager after you install that windows.

If you're lost, search google for help

Minitool partition wizard free :- http://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html